# Foobar Test Case Failing on my solution on decrypting input

Tags: python, encryption

every lowercase letter [a..z] is replaced with the corresponding one in [z..a], while every other character (including uppercase letters and punctuation) is left untouched.  That is, 'a' becomes 'z', 'b' becomes 'y', 'c' becomes 'x', etc.  For instance, the word ""vmxibkgrlm"", when decoded, would become ""encryption"".

Write a function called solution(s) which takes in a string and returns the deciphered string so you can show the commander proof that these minions are talking about ""Lance & Janice"" instead of doing their jobs.

```
def solution(x):
    alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    decryptDic = {}
    alph_len = (len(alph) -1)
    response =""
    for i in alph:      
        decryptDic[i] = alph[alph_len]
        alph_len = alph_len-1      
    for char in  x:
        if char == char.upper():
            response = f"{response}{char}"      
        elif char not in decryptDic:
            response = response.join(char)
        else:
            response = f"{response}{(decryptDic.get(char))}"

    return response
```

It is just saying test case failed

Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Python cases --

Input:
solution.solution("wrw blf hvv ozhg mrtsg'h vkrhlwv?")

Output:
did you see last night's episode?

Comment: As this is a homework problem, what have you done to try and debug your problem? I would start with verifying your `decryptDic` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Yes if i send the encrypted sentence it comes back with the right response, as in thr test cases

Comment: Are you sure it is failing that test case? the question says there may be hidden cases. I would try testing EVERY character on your keyboard and verifying that they don't break something.

Comment: @Pepsi-Joe so its not a homework assignment, so its part of the foobar with google test thing and the code works with all the keys as it should the issue came that i just found they are using Python 2.7 and not python 3 so i got a syntax error on ` response = f"{response}{char}" `to join the strings i changed it to `  response = response+char ` for the test cases and it all passed, thank you for the assistance i went to check twice all my characters

Comment: Glad you found the error! I was going to comment that it would be better to use `+` in your case there as it is more readable than `f-strings` when you don't have anything else in the strings. My guess was that your error lay in a hidden test case that included quotes and so it was breaking the string up somehow. I'm glad it wasn't as I wouldn't have know how to fix it!

Comment: @Pepsi-Joe XD XD thank you

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have found your problem, I thought it may be worth giving you a slightly more pythonic version of your code:

```
def solution(x):
    alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    response = ""
    
    decryptDic = {c : c_prime for c, c_prime in zip(alph, alph[::-1])}
    
    for char in  x:
        if char == char.upper() or char not in decryptDic:
            response += char    
        else:
            response += (decryptDic.get(char))

    return response
```

Explanation:

- `{c : c_prime for c, c_prime in zip(alph, alph[::-1])}` is a dict comprehension where you can replace your loop with one line which is more readable. `alph[::-1]` reverses your string and `zip` "zips" together two iterables element wise.
- The logic has only two options (add character to string or add translated character to string) so you can combine two of your statements into one. I think you could probably drop the `if char == char.upper()` too as your `alph` doesn't include any upper case letter too if you want.
- `x += s` is a more compact way of writing `x = x + s` and is backward compatible with Python 2.7. `f-strings` are preferred when you need to insert variables into strings.

Comment: Shortening that looks so much better and more efficient thank you

Comment: `{c : c_prime for c, c_prime in zip(alph, alph[::-1])}`  im definitely going to start changing to use this